# jquery: Change table row background color in a even tr

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have the following code (part of) in a php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".MyYable tr:even").addClass("alt");
    jQuery("table tr").click(function(){
       var row = jQuery(this);
       var hasClass = row.hasClass("highlight");
       jQuery("table tr").removeClass("highlight");
       if(!hasClass){
         row.addClass("highlight");
       }
    });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">

.highlight{
background-color:#00FF00;
}
tr.alt td {
background:#CCCCCC;
}
tr.over td {
background-color:#00FF00;   
}
</style>

        <table id="Tabela_lista_empresas" width="751">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="300"><strong>Descrição</strong></th>
            <th width="100" align="center"><strong>Qtd</strong></th>
            <th width="100" align="center"><strong>Refª cliente</strong></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <?php do {?>

          <tr <?php echo $i++ % 2 ? 'class="odd"' : ''; ?> onClick="get(<?php echo $row_rs_listaequipamentos['id_equipamento']; ?>, this)">
            <td width="300"><?php echo $row_rs_listaequipamentos['descricao_curta']; ?></td>
            <td width="100" align="center"><?php echo $row_rs_listaequipamentos['quantidade']; ?> <?php echo $row_rs_listaequipamentos['unidades']; ?></td>
            <td width="100" align="center"><?php echo $row_rs_listaequipamentos['referenciacliente']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_rs_listaequipamentos = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_listaequipamentos)); ?>
        </table>
```

In my case, when I click in a odd row, it will change the class to "highlight", but if I click on a even row nothing happens.
Any help is appreciated.
Note: I'm trying to learn "by-my-self", so I'm not an expert in programming.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why not use the css `:hover` selector?

```
tr.over td {
background-color:#00FF00;   
}
tr.over td:hover {
background-color:#FFFF00;   
}
```

Comment: Good question and it's better like you said, but could you help me change my code for that effect? Thank you.

Comment: lose the jquery and add my css example. then adjust it for your colors after reading the documentation on `:hover`